# How often should I dust the inside of my computer?

Tags: cleaning, maintenance

I would like to avoid frying my computer.  I understand dust collects inside on the boards and the CPU cooling unit.  How often should I open up the chassis and what process should I use to safely remove the dust?

Comment: My father once hoovered inside his computer. It stopped working after that. Just a heads up.

Comment: Yeah, most vacuums are sources of computer-killing static electricity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This depends greatly on how dusty your house is. I open mine up every few months, and use some pressurized air to blow out all the vents, etc.

You'll want to pay special attention to the areas that usually get hot - for instance, the CPU. Make sure there's proper air flow through the system, and if you turn your computer off a lot, you'll notice a build-up on the fans as well.

If you live in a dusty area, or are a smoker, you'll want to do this on a very regular basis.

Answer (score 5):

Its a good idea to run temp monitoring software in your systray (like [motherboard monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherboard_Monitor))  to watch the ambient/Cpu temps - this should allay your concerns with frying your machine.  Typically if your CPU cooling / case ventilation fans are installed properly, you SHOULDN'T have cooling problems.

Most modern cases have filters on the fans that draw air into the case as well.

That said, compressed air is your best bet.  Unless your house is super dusty or you're a smoker, chances are you can get by blowing it out with an air duster a few times a year.

Your main cleaning areas should be

- CPU heatsink/fan assembly
- motherboard chipset fan assembly
- powersupply if accessible
- case fans
- hard drives.

Answer (score 3):

Don't dust.

Air in a can instead.

If your fans seem to be speeding up sooner than before, its time for a clean. Thats the rule I go by.

Best practice is to keep the area clean though!

Answer (score 2):

I think most users should **never** dust the inside of their computer.

I won't say that I haven't done that with my pc ever, but I do know that I can count the times I have done that on one hand. But then I'm not like 'most users'.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your computer area clean and dust free as much as possible around the outside of your computer, most computers should last a few years without inside dusting.  But I personally open mine every 6-12 months just to give it a good compressed air blast.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I clean my PC at least once a month just to reduce the build-up inside. Disconnect the cables, take the motherboard out, clean the casing and the fans, and put them back in.

It's rather dusty where I live, and since we don't have airconditioning, that's what we usually do.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother. By the time there is enough dust to cause a problem, the computer is probably obsolete. =)

Comment: How do you finish them off?